# I want to know why the two div which have the same height but different

Tags: html, css

```
    <div id="nav_bar">

    </div>
    <div id="blank"></div>

    #nav_bar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;

}

#blank{
    height: 50px;
}
```

these are my codes. 
I think these two div would have the same height so the `'nav_bar'` would cover `'blank'`.
 but the result is 'blank' will longer than 'nav_bar' 
I want to know why???Thank you !!

Comment: because you used: position: fixed;

Comment: I tested your code is the same height

Comment: but in my screen  the 'blank' will longer a little than 'nav_bar'

Comment: I forgot to add';'    but in my code  is "left:0px ;" sorry~~~!

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer mentioned, you forgot a `;` after the `left:` in `#nav_bar`.

The `position: fixed;` property makes the two elements overlap each other, which is why it may look like that one is shorter than the other. Unless you intentionally want them to overlap, remove the `position: fixed;` and they will set vertically relative as such:

```css
 #nav_bar {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background: red;
}

#blank {
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_bar"></div>
<div id="blank"></div>
```

Please feel free to ask if you have any more questions.

Comment: thank you  but  I am still confused why  when I  use position:fixed   the 'nav_bar' and the 'blank'  have the same height but  on my screen the 'blank' is  longer a little than 'nav_bar'

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a `;` after the `left` in `#nav_bar`.

Here is the issue,

[image]

```css
    #nav_bar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;

}

#blank{
    height: 50px;
}

div {
  border:solid 1px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="nav_bar">

    </div>
    <div id="blank"></div>
```

Comment: thank you  but when I add the ";"  the result is still the 'blank' longer than'nav_bar"

Comment: In you snippet they are in the same length